# 3Jekyll .1.6 does not serve on Ubuntu: undefined method `bash_on_windows?' for Jekyll:: Utils:: Platforms: Module

Tags: jekyll

I installed jekyll

> sudo gem install jekyll

And then I go into my GitHub repo folder (which has file `index.html`) and

> jekyll serve

But it generates error:

> /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/drops/document_drop.rb:8: warning: already initialized constant
>
> Jekyll::Drops::DocumentDrop::NESTED_OBJECT_FIELD_BLACKLIST
>
> /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/drops/document_drop.rb:8: warning: previous definition of NESTED_OBJECT_FIELD_BLACKLIST was here
>
> /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/drops/drop.rb:8: warning: already initialized constant Jekyll::Drops::Drop::NON_CONTENT_METHODS
>
> /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/drops/drop.rb:8: warning: previous definition of NON_CONTENT_METHODS was here
>
> Configuration file: none
>
> Configuration file: none
>
> Configuration file: none
>
> ```
>         Source: /home/chi/eivorjussila.github.io
>
>    Destination: /home/chi/eivorjussila.github.io/_site
> ```
>
> Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
>
> ```
>  Generating... 
>
>                done in 0.095 seconds.
> ```
>
> jekyll 3.1.6 | Error:  undefined method `bash_on_windows?' for Jekyll::Utils::Platforms:Module

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 5):

it seems that i have 2 versions of jekyll.
so what i did was to 

`sudo apt remove jekyll
sudo apt-get --autoremove
which jekyll
sudo rm /bin../jekyll`

and then i reinstall it

`sudo gem install jekyll`

it works now

Comment: Thank you! one difference: `sudo apt autoremove`